# Adding function to bash script resulting error

Tags: bash

I'm trying to add a timestamp to the log script that I have based on [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/310098/how-to-add-a-timestamp-to-bash-script-log). I'm new in bash, but I think this supossed to be working but it does not. Which part I did something wrong?

`dothing.sh` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

adddate() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf '%s %s\n' "$(date)" "$line";
    done
}

/home/astden01a000/app/anaconda3/envs/dataengineer/bin/python "/scripts/ixi/bin/framework_develope/script/project_x/engine_trigger_file.py" "/scripts/ixi/bin/properties/CashX.cfg" "bulk" "prod" | adddate > /data04/eva/tax/hi/garu/outstanding/development/cronjob/log_run_ingest_cod.txt
```

But when I try to run the bash script `bash dothing.sh` it says `syntax error near unexpected token` $'{\r''``

Comment: In other words, you script seems to have windows line endings with carriage returns; run the file through `dos2unix` first.

Comment: @ImBaldingPleaseHelp, which text editor are you using to create your file, on which operating system? Using a Windows editor to create a file you then run on a UNIX system is the easiest way to get this problem. (Some UNIX editors will _keep_ text files in DOS file formats if they were loaded that way, in vim, `:set fileformat=unix` will turn that off).

Comment: fwiw ... from a performance perspective, especially if running a lot of output/lines through this function, you'll want to replace `$(date)` as this will invoke a cpu-/time-intensive subprocess each time it's called; consider replacing with `printf -v logdt '%(%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S)T'` (adjust format as desired) and then `printf "%s %s\n" "${logdt}" "${line}"`; the `printf -v ... <date_format>` does not invoke a subprocess so on large volumes of calls you can be looking at a difference of a couple magnitudes in performance ...

Comment: see the difference with these two tests: `time for i in {1..100}; do echo "$(date)" > /dev/null; done` and `time for i in {1..100}; do printf -v x '%(%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S)T'; echo "$x" > /dev/null; done`

Comment: re: `\r` (windows/dos line ending); run `od -c dothing.sh` and review the output; if you see `\r` then this confirms what others have said ... the script has windows/dos endings and needs to be edited to remove said characters (eg, `dos2unix dothing.sh`)